# foreach trouble

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to display an image from an XML request for each unique ID. A total of three images should be displayed, but I'm getting the same image three times.

The IDs are storing correctly here:

```
    $simIds = array(
    "id1" => $similarObject->place[0]['place_id'],
    "id2" => $similarObject->place[1]['place_id'],
    "id3" => $similarObject->place[2]['place_id'],
);
```

Here's my foreach loop:

```
foreach ($simIds as $foo) {
    $simPhotoFile = $photoUrl.$foo;
    $simPhotoObject = simplexml_load_file($simPhotoFile);
    $simPhotoSrc = array (
        'src1' => $simPhotoObject->photos->photo_set->square,
        'src2' => $simPhotoObject->photos->photo_set->square,
        'src3' => $simPhotoObject->photos->photo_set->square,       
    );  
}
```

The relevant HTML:

```
<p><img src="<?= $simPhotoSrc['src1'] ?>" alt="Image load failed" /><img src="<?= $simPhotoSrc['src2'] ?>" alt="Image load failed" /><img src="<?= $simPhotoSrc['src3'] ?>" alt="Image load failed" /></p>
```

Im not really sure what I'm doing wrong at this point, or if there is maybe a better way to go about this. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why are you keying them "Id1" instead of using an array? Why are you hard-coding an array when you simply want a variable value `function simIDAt(id){ return place[id]['placeid'];}` ? Stop working so hard.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand how this works. You've declared a funtion called simIDAt that's being fed a variable "id" and it returns a variable place[id]['place_id'] ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$simPhotoSrc = array();
foreach ($simIds as $foo) {
    $simPhotoFile = $photoUrl.$foo;
    $simPhotoObject = simplexml_load_file($simPhotoFile);
    $simPhotoSrc[] = $simPhotoObject->photos->photo_set->square
}
```

html:

```
<p><img src="<?= $simPhotoSrc[0] ?>"/><img src="<?= $simPhotoSrc[1] ?>" /><img src="<?= $simPhotoSrc[2] ?>" /></p>
```

Comment: I tried this and get no images loading at all. $simPhotoSrc[0] outputs nothing when printed. I can see what you were going for, I just don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: Nevermind, I was missing one extra xml tag: $simPhotoSrc[] = $simPhotoObject->**photos**->photo_set->square; It's working perfectly now, thanks!